# Cannot find the "event" in a probability problem that asks for "at least"

Tags: probability

The unemployment of a city is of 10%. If we take 100 people what is the probability of at leat 15 be unemployed. I am doing my homework and I am having difficulty in this one. I am asked to find the "sample", "success", "failure" and "event". Those are the terms we use in portuguese transtalted to english. I hope they are the same. Using the binomial formula, the sample would be 100, the success would be 0,1 and the failure would be 0,9. I am having a hard time to figure out the "event". What the event would be? I am using this calculator

[calculator](https://matheussouza89.github.io/HuygensSystem/index.html#scrolling2)

I put 100 on the first input, 10 on the second, 90 on the third and the fourth for the event and don't know. I get wrong results. I know it because my homework has the answers. I just have to find the variables. The answer is 7,26

Answer (score 1):

Manually, boring but not impossible,  you can calculate

$$1-\sum_{k=0}^{14}\binom{100}{k}0.1^k\cdot 0.9^{100-k}\approx 7.26\%$$

If you want a quick approximation you can use the Central limit Therorem finding immediately

$$\mathbb{P}[X\geq 15]=1-\Phi\Bigg[\frac{14.5-10}{\sqrt{9}}\Bigg]=1-\Phi(1.5)\approx 6.68\%$$